# Redirection to /?authResult=error whenever there is an error while logging using social connector

Tags: social-connected

Whenever there is an error while logging in through facebook using Sitecore social connector, we get redirected to a url with query string `/?authResult=error`

But how do we get the cause of the error? Which pipeline do we use to catch and show the appropriate error message to the client?

Comment: What exception do you see in logs? Which Sitecore and Social Connector version you are on?